# Convert API response from string to array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, split

How can I convert an API response from string to an array of objects?

I am making a GET call as follows and the result I get is returned as one very long string:

```
const state = {
    strict: true,
    airports: []
};

const getters = {
    allAirports: (state) => state.airports,
};

const actions = {
    getAirports({ commit }) {
        axios.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat')
            .then(response => {
                commit('SET_AIRPORTS', response.data)
            })
    }
};

const mutations = {
    SET_AIRPORTS(state, airports) {
        state.airports = airports
    }
};
```

And the response is:

```
1,"Goroka Airport","Goroka","Papua New Guinea","GKA","AYGA",-6.081689834590001,145.391998291,5282,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby","airport","OurAirports" 2,"Madang Airport","Madang","Papua New Guinea","MAG","AYMD",-5.20707988739,145.789001465,20,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby","airport","OurAirports" 3,"Mount Hagen Kagamuga Airport","Mount Hagen","Papua New Guinea","HGU","AYMH",-5.826789855957031,144.29600524902344,5388,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby","airport","OurAirports" 4,"Nadzab Airport","Nadzab","Papua New Guinea","LAE","AYNZ",-6.569803,146.725977,239,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby","airport","OurAirports" 5,"Port Moresby Jacksons International Airport","Port Moresby","Papua New Guinea","POM","AYPY",-9.443380355834961,147.22000122070312,146,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby","airport","OurAirports" 6,"Wewak International Airport","Wewak","Papua New Guinea","WWK","AYWK",-3.58383011818,143.669006348,19,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby","airport","OurAirports" 7,"Narsarsuaq Airport","Narssarssuaq","Greenland","UAK","BGBW",61.1604995728,-45.4259986877,112,-3,"E","America/Godthab","airport","OurAirports" 8,"Godthaab / Nuuk Airport","Godthaab","Greenland","GOH","BGGH",64.19090271,-51.6781005859,283,-3,"E","America/Godthab","airport","OurAirports" 9,"Kangerlussuaq Airport","Sondrestrom","Greenland","SFJ","BGSF",67.0122218992,-50.7116031647,165,-3,"E","America/Godthab","airport","OurAirports"
```

However, my goal is that once the call is made, this string is divided in several objects and added to the `airports` array as follows:

```
airports: [
  {
   id: 1,
   name: 'Goroka Airport',
   city: 'Goroka',
   country: 'Papua New Guinea',
   iata: 'GKA',
   icao: 'AYGA',
   longitude: -6.081689834590001,
   latitude: 145.391998291
  }
  {
   etc...
  }
]
```

Can you please advise how can I achieve the above?

Comment: This question is more like [Where could I find some JavaScript code to parse CSV data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/example-javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To get the individual lines of data, use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with `\n` as the separator on the text response from the [URL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat).
2. Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert each line:

   a. Parse the comma-separated fields from the line by using [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with `,` as the separator.

   b. Strip redundant quotes from the fields by using [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [regular expression that matches leading/trailing quotes](https://regex101.com/r/hUWJwC/1) and an empty string as the replacement.

   c. Return an object with the desired named fields.

```js
const actions = {
  getAirports({ commit }) {
    axios
      .get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat')
      .then(response => {
        // 1️.
        const lines = response.data.split('\n');
        // 2️.
        const airports = lines.map(line => {
          const fields = line.split(',') // 2a.
                            .map(x => x.replace(/(^"|"$)/g, '')); // 2b.

          // 2c.
          return {
            id: fields[0],
            name: fields[1],
            city: fields[2],
            country: fields[3],
            iata: fields[4],
            icao: fields[5],
            longitude: fields[6],
            latitude: fields[7],
          };
        });

        commit('SET_AIRPORTS', airports);
      })
  }
};
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-parsing-airport-csv-data?file=src/store.js)

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the answer! I liked your approach the most, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Written in simple and understandable code

```js
var WholeString = [1,"Goroka Airport","Goroka","Papua New Guinea","GKA","AYGA",-6.081689834590001,145.391998291,5282,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby","airport","OurAirports",2,"Madang Airport","Madang","Papua New Guinea","MAG","AYMD",-5.20707988739,145.789001465,20,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby","airport","OurAirports"];


var fullarray = WholeString;    //.split(',');

var i = 0;
var airportArray = []; 

fullarray.forEach(function callbackFn(value, index) {

  if (typeof airportArray[i] == 'undefined') {
    airportArray[i] = [];
  }
    
  airportArray[i].push(value);
  
  if((index+1)%14==0 && index!=0)
  {
    i++;
  }

});


var j = 0;
var finalArr = [];
airportArray.forEach(function callbackFn(value, index) {
    finalArr.push({
        id: value[0],
        name: value[1],
        city: value[2],
        country: value[3],
        iata: value[4],
        icao: value[5],
        longitude: value[6],
        latitude: value[7],
    });

});


console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are certain about the length of the object then you can try this

```
const prototype = {
   id: '',
   name: '',
   city: '',   
   country: '',
   iata: '',
   icao: '',
   longitude: '',
   latitude: ''
}
const arr = [1,"Goroka Airport","Goroka","Papua New Guinea","GKA","AYGA",-6.081689834590001,145.391998291]
let chunked = []  //* final  output
let chunk = 8 //* chunk length



for (let i = 0; i< arr.length; i+=chunk) {
  let obj = {}
  let temp = arr.slice(i, i+chunk)
  
 
  Object.keys(prototype).map((key,i)=>{
     obj[key] = temp[i]
  })
  chunked = [...chunked,obj]
}


console.log(chunked)
```

```js
const prototype = {
   id: '',
   name: '',
   city: '',   
   country: '',
   iata: '',
   icao: '',
   longitude: '',
   latitude: ''
}
const arr = [1,"Goroka Airport","Goroka","Papua New Guinea","GKA","AYGA",-6.081689834590001,145.391998291]
let chunked = []  //* final  output
let chunk = 8 //* chunk length



for (let i = 0; i< arr.length; i+=chunk) {
  let obj = {}
  let temp = arr.slice(i, i+chunk)
  
 
  Object.keys(prototype).map((key,i)=>{
     obj[key] = temp[i]
  })
  chunked = [...chunked,obj]
}


console.log(chunked)
```